# Why does ARR-Disable-Session-Affinity not work in Azure Web App

Tags: azure-web-app-service, session-affinity

I have a project requirement that when a request is processed by a specific MVC controller that ARR Affinity is turned off.  After trying and failing to get this to work in the cloud I created a simple Test Application that proves that it does not work.  Per [Disabling ARR's Instance Affinity](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/disabling-arrs-instance-affinity-in-windows-azure-web-sites/) I just need to add a response header.  So to test this I created a default .NET framework 4.8 MVC web application, and modified the home controller as indicated below:

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = $"Your index page.'{System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID")}'";
        Response.Headers.Add("ARR-Disable-Session-Affinity", "True");
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = $"Your application description page.'{System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID")}'";
        Response.Headers.Add("ARR-Disable-Session-Affinity", "True");
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = $"Your contact page.'{System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID")}'";

        Response.Headers.Add("ARR-Disable-Session-Affinity", "True");
        return View();
    }
}
```

I added this code `<h3>@ViewBag.Message</h3>` to the index.cshtml page and deployed to an Azure Windows web application with 2 instances.  This is what I see when I navigate to every page using the menu.

[image]

[image]

[image]

As shown the first page might hit a particular instance.  Then that instance changes.  After that the instance never changes.  Does anyone have any ideas of what I am doing wrong if anything or does this not work anymore under an Azure Windows Web Application?

Comment: Are you looking for same instance ID in all the Instances?

Comment: No I would expect the instance id to change with every controller action.  I expect to leave ARR affinity on in Azure web application and for the controller actions to cause the load balancer to switch the instance.

Answer (score 0):

***I tried your code in my environment and got the Web App instance ID in my browser.***

**Code** :

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace arrafinity.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = $"Your index page.'{System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID")}'";
            Response.Headers.Add("ARR-Disable-Session-Affinity", "True");
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = $"Your application description page.'{System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID")}'";
            Response.Headers.Add("ARR-Disable-Session-Affinity", "True");
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = $"Your contact page.'{System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID")}'";

            Response.Headers.Add("ARR-Disable-Session-Affinity", "True");
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

**index.cshtml** :

```html
<h3>@ViewBag.Message</h3>
```

I publish the above code to the Azure Web App Services below:

[image]

I added two instance counts to the Web app below.

[image]

By default, **ARR affinity** is set to be **on**.

[image]

***Then, I browsed the Web app in the Azure portal and got the same instance ID below***,

**Output** :

[image]

[image]

[image]

***If I set the ARR affinity to Off, I got different instance ID's below.***

[image]

**Output** :

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I need ARR affinity left on so that I can pragmatically control when the session switches to another instance.

Comment: @bmukes can check the azure webapp url in different browsers like chrome and microsoft edge

Comment: I have already tried this under both Edge and Chrome the result is the same.

Comment: @bmukes I observed you got two different instance Ids, so when I changed the instances 2 to 3 I got different instance Ids for Home, About, Contact.

Comment: I update the service plan to have 3 instances and I do NOT get 3 different ID's which is the expected results.  Stack Overflow will not let me paste the images as proof in the comments.

Comment: @bmukes for me it changes only in chrome in my device only.